# Warning: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql, pdo

In my news.php file I have this code below, to read my function Paginator with my `$search` variable, if user send this field. And if user didnt post my input I call my Paginator
without `$search` variable.

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != 'Search:'){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    Paginator('news', "WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC", $max, $link, $pag, $search);
}
else{
    Paginator('news', "ORDER BY date DESC", $max, $link, $pag);
}
```

And then in my function Paginator I want to do a different select, depending if I pass my variable $search (if user post this variable) or not.

So below this is my function to do a paginator: (but I only put here the part of function important to my issue)

```
function Paginator($table, $cond, $max, $link, $pag, $search = NULL){
    $pdo = conect();
    if($search){
        $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} {$cond}");
        $read->bindValue(1,"%$search%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $read->bindParam(2,$table,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $read->bindParam(3,$cond,PDO::PARAM_STR);       
    }
    else{
        $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} {$cond}");
        $read->bindParam(1,$table,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $read->bindParam(2,$cond,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }

    $read->execute();
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form name="searchpost" action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="search" onclick="if(this.value=='Search:')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search:'" value="Search:" />
     <input type="submit" value="Search"  name="sendForm" />
</form>
```

But Im having always this error:

*Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in my function Paginator in $read->execute();*

Can you give some help trying to find what Im doing wrong?

Comment: `$table` and `$cond` should not be bound to the query.

Comment: So why are you binding 3 variables when your query has only one? Table name's cant be bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind values in a PDO statement, not table- or column names or complete sections of sql.

Apart from that you are not even using placeholders for your table name and conditions string (I assume `$tabela` is just a typo).

So you only bind one variable in the `if` statement and none in the `else` section (which you don't need anyway...):

```
$read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} {$cond}");
if($search){
    $read->bindValue(1,"%$search%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

To avoid sql injection problems you should use a white-list for the variables you inject directly in the sql.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer jeroen. But If I dont submit my form I get my results with my pagination fine, so it seems that works bind my table and my condition with pdo! And I think I need my else because IF I dont submit my form I want to select without my like statement!

Comment: And my query is also ok, If submit form and I print_r my $read I get PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC ) and If I dont submit I get PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC ).

Comment: Well, but I tried your code, and it works! Now I dont have my error!  But its strange, because before Im doing this search form, I was using already my Paginator function to have a pagination in my news.php, and I was binding my table, so I dont understand why now dont works! However my pagination is not working fine, but your solution works, thanks!

Comment: @OzzC Strange, I don't see how any of your original sql statements could work as you were binding too many values. But if it works now I guess that doesn't matter any more...